# Actual size not growing

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I am installing a program on Linux installed inside VirtualBox. The installation was aborted with a message that there are 0 bytes of free space left on disk.

However, from the image below, I would expect that the disk size would still be able to grow 15 GB (difference between virtual size and actual size).

[image]

What is happening?

Comment: The virtual hdd will grow that doesn't mean the partitions will grow automatically.  How you do that is well documented.

Comment: Then how can I make the partitions grow?

Comment: What does your research say?  It's literally the most documented procedure on the web